# How can I insert icons in AppBar with Scenebuilder - JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder, gluon

I'm trying to insert this icon into this AppBar object, but it refuse it accept it. Why? 
The orginal template with the AppBar have an icon inserted from the beginning. But I want to learn how I can insert icon by my self from scratch.

[image]

Here is the orginal template:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to do that is wrap the `AppBar` and the `Icon` inside an `AnchorPane`:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyPpU.png)

EDIT: if you look at the `fxml` files you can notice that the **template** result is achived using `navIcon` with a `button` and a `icon`:

```xml
<AppBar titleText="Screen Title" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
    <navIcon>
        <Button>
            <graphic>
                <Icon content="ARROW_BACK" />
            </graphic>
        </Button>
    </navIcon>
</AppBar>
```

I'm not able to reproduce this result via SceneBuilder, maybe it's not a supported feature, despite this very example comes from SceneBuilder itself...

Comment: But orginal temple does not use AnchorPane.

Comment: I added a picture to my question

Comment: So how am I suppose to add a navicon to AppBar? I don't want to modify the HTML file.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but unfortunately not every feature of JavaFX is available in SceneBuilder. If you want to have the **same** result, without an `AnchorPane`, you need to manually edit the `fxml` file or add the `icon` via Java code.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I think that would be the answer. Thank you!